# XMLRPC - wp.newPost with custom post type and custom fields

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm trying to add new posts over XMLRPC, but for some reason I cannot add custom fields (other content like title and description works).

Pseudo code that I use:

```
from xmlrpc import client
user = 'admin'
passwd = 'pass'
server = client.ServerProxy('http://domain.tld/xmlrpc.php')
blog_id = 0

custom_fields = []
custom_fields.append(
         {'key' : 'my_meta_key', 'value' : 123}
)

blog_content = {
    'post_title': title,
    'post_content': content,
    'post_type': 'product',
    'custom_fields': custom_fields
}

post_id = int(server.wp.newPost(blog_id, user, passwd, blog_content, 0))
```

Posts gets added, however my custom field named `my_meta_key` is empty.

Cant see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with naming of meta keys. I name them with underscore, like `_my_meta_key`, which means they are protected for the API.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
custom_fields = {}    
custom_fields.update(
         {'my_meta_key': 123}
```

)

Comment: Not working. Cant really spot where the problem is. Over PHP adding post meta work for same key.

Comment: What is the error that  you are getting after using dict instead of list?

Comment: There is no error. Post gets created and filled with title and content. However meta key is not populated.

Comment: You can refer to the link below:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419768/using-python-xml-rpc-to-add-a-custom-field-to-a-wordpress-post?rq=1)